# Working with list elements in python lists

Tags: python, list

The idea is to append values to list element in a list. So there is a list, which consists of lists. For example, there is a list 'a', consisting of two lists "A" and "B". I would like to create a new list, consisting of the first list of 'a' (a[0]) and append a value 1 to it without modifying the original list 'a'.

```
a=[["A"],["B"]]
b = a[0]
b.append("1")
print a
```

The result of print a:

```
[['A', '1'], ['B']]
```

But I want is that the list 'a' does not change. The list b equals ['A', '1'] is what I need.

Comment: `b = a[0][:]` is enough to create a copy of the nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy  `a[0]` with `a[0][:]`:

```
>>> a = [["A"],["B"]]
>>> b = a[0][:]
>>> b.append("1")
>>> a
[['A'], ['B']]
>>> b
['A', '1']
```